# Keep getting error ""Create Service - Failed to fetch" on IBM Cloud's Db2 page

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-storage

I've tried, failed, deleted the database and tried again 7 times now and I get this error each time. I'm on the lite plan and taking the IBM Data Science Certification course and I can't get past this part. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Deleting database (can only have one in lite plan I believe) retried several times

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the vendor support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just verified that I am able to create a fully working Lite instance on my end. Is it possible that it's a networking issue on your end? Was that the full error message? It seems to be cut off. In what region and datacenter are you trying to create the service instance?

Comment: Thank you, it was apparently my VPN interfering.